# How to mix Vaadin and Thymeleaf/Static HTML?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, thymeleaf, vaadin8

I've built a site in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf but the logic is getting too messy. Vaadin seems to be the right answer but how can I mix it with Thymeleaf?

What I want is to embed Vaadin into the Thymeleaf template. 
What I want to avoid is converting all the markup to Java, that would be tedious.

I'd even settle for templating in Vaadin but it seems to lack this.

---

TL;DR - how can I include static boilerplate HTML (preferably Thymeleaf) in a Vaadin app?

... or vice versa, include a Vaadin app in Thymeleaf (or static HTML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static HTML generated by Thymeleaf in CustomLayout Component of vaadin:

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html

It is also possible to embed vaadin inside a `<div>`.

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding.html